# When using @GetMapping in Spring, how do I add two or more objects for a web page?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to build a web page that show the status of list of objects *from* a database table called devapi. The objects can have statuses like "pending", "in operation", "suspended", etc. Now, in the table the status column is set as Integer, because this site will be multilingual. (proper localization to come later in development)

However, I do not know how to add or more objects when using @GetMapping. Or even if this is the right approach.

In the Configuration file I have:

```
    @GetMapping("/dev_apis")
    public String dev_apis(Model model){
        List<DevApiDto> dev_apis = devApiServiceImpl.findAllDevApis();
        model.addAttribute("dev_apis", dev_apis);
        
        
          String[] status = devApiServiceImpl.getStatusArray();
          
          status[0] = "default"; 
          status[1] = "pending"; 
          status[2] = "in operation";
          status[3] = "suspended"; 
          status[4] = "terminated";
          
          model.addAttribute("dev_apis", status);
          
        return "dev_apis";
    }
```

This function is fine up until *model.addAttribute("dev_apis", status)* when status does not get added to dev_apis.

My gut tells me this is the wrong approach, but Dr. Google has not been forthcoming.

Comment: Why are you adding 2 different objects under same key `dev_apis`?

Comment: Because, I do not know how else to do so :-)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish with the `status` array and passing it to the model.